# Jenkins, how can I know that jenkins run on the right plan? I use playwright

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, playwright

I do automated testing on web using playwright. Try to use Jenkins to run regrassion test. Jenkins keep fail and I look into the log and there is nothing wrong with the script and web. They passed on local execution.

1. How can I know if I configure it to the right environment?
   2.Can it show in console output, cause I check the branch is already correct.
   3.How will it display index.html? sometime it shows sometimes it doesn't.

Please I am so new in this thing, thankyou

Comment: Is there no error in the console log?

Comment: It shows error on console log but noe specific to the environment I tested, I would like to rule out first that I execute on the right environment, please help

Comment: What do you mean by "right environment"? Do you have multiple Jenkins agents?

Comment: I mean in one repository I have many environment and I go by set up environment in configuration. But the environment issue has been solved. Thankssss